# How to change collider during game play?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In the game the scale of the gameObject change during the game play with this line of code:
`transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localScale,new Vector3(0.75f,0.25f,0.75f),7*Time.deltaTime);`
How can I change the collider to become as the same as shape of the gameObject?
The gameObject is a sphere.

`transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localScale,new Vector3(0.75f,0.25f,0.75f),7*Time.deltaTime);`

Answer (score 0):

in general the issue is that a `SphereCollider` in Unity is always unscaled - at least the visuals use the maximum of the lossy scale components * radius for all axis (Basically because within the physics engine this is not a sphere shape but solely a center point + radius => Th cheapest of all collision detections ;) )

[image]

so if you actually need to go with the exact scaled down sphere shape you will need to go with a `MeshCollider` (remember to enable `Convex` which is required for most of physics) instead and do e.g.

[image]

You will get a warning because the built-in sphere mesh (which will automatically used from the `MeshFilter`) has a lot faces so the `MeshCollider` will use a reduced hull